# WebRTC group video call not displaying media(video/audio) of some users

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, video-streaming, webrtc

I am creating a group video call application based on WebRTC. But sometimes people are not able to view or hear each other. In the same group 2 or more people can communicate with each other but not with rest of people in group call.

Creating peer connection as below -

```
var peer_connection = new RTCPeerConnection(
        {"iceServers": ICE_SERVERS},
        {"optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]}
);
```

Using Below iCE servers -

```
var ICE_SERVERS = [
{
    urls:"stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302",
},
{
    'urls': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
    'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
    'username': '28224511:1379330808'
},
{
    'urls': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
    'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
    'username': '28224511:1379330808'
}];
```

Adding ICE candidate as below -

```
peer.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(ice_candidate)).catch(e => {
    console.log("Failure during addIceCandidate(): ", e);
});
```

Offer is created successfully, connection is also created. But inside ***ontrack*** function, media is not displayed. 
Function is as below -

```
peer_connection.ontrack = function(event) {
    if(mediaStreams.indexOf(event.streams[0].id) === -1){
        var remote_media = "<video playsinline>";
        remote_media.attr("autoplay", "autoplay");

        $('#connects').append(remote_media);
        attachMediaStream(remote_media[0], event.streams[0]);
    }
};
attachMediaStream = function(element, stream) {
    element.srcObject = stream;
};
```

***NOTE***: This issue is not there when we test application in same network.

Can anybody please suggest what issue can be and what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: running your own turn servers instead of blindly copying someone elses credentials from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/ will probably help.

Comment: @PhilippHancke, I added my own stun server, Still facing same issue

Comment: @PhilippHancke, implementing SFU will help to resolve this issue or not? Also is mediasoup a good option for SFU?